# PHP form - Registration Successful Message on New Page

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, registration

I coded a registration form and after every input has been validated , it sends some data to the database and redirects to the login page.

I want to display a message on the login page tho like : Registration Successful - Login Here

```
if (!validated() {
    // post error messages

} else {
    echo '
       <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>Registration Complete</h3>
        </div>
       </div>';

    header( 'Location: ../login.php' );
}
```

Login file :

```
Header - Navbar

<div class="container">
   <div class="page-header">
       <h3>Login To Members Corner</h3>
   </div>

   <form>
       // login form
   </form>

Footer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect to a file after output has been shown. You have two alternate solutions here:

1. Refresh the page after a timeout while showing the message in the meantime, using a `<meta>` tag:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=../login.php">
   ```
2. Output the message after redirection:

   ```
   <?php 
   header('Location: ../login.php?registered=true');
   ```

   And in login.php:

   ```
   <?php
   if (@$_GET['registered'] == 'true')
       echo 'You have registered successfully.'
   ```

Comment: Is `isset()` can replace `@`?

Comment: @ suppresses errors on the expression it is tied to, in this case @ will supress any errors that will raise from the variable not existing. So it's roughly equivalent to `isset($...) && $...`, fundementally different but in this case provides the same usage. Don't overdo it though, it's bad practice.

Comment: Is that mean it is better to use `isset()` than suppress the warning?

Comment: As long as you know when it's okay to use @ then it's not a big problem, *never* use it for supressing errors in functions or included pages, but if you need it specifically for things like $_GET not existing or the likes, it's okay - just use proper judgement

Answer (score 2):

You do a `header("Location")` to redirect the page. That is possible but than you want to add a paremeter where you can detect if the registration was successful. Something like:

```
header( 'Location: ../login.php?action=success' );
```

And than in you file do this:

```
if( $_GET['action'] == 'success' ) {
    echo "thanks for you registration, log in here";
```

}

Because if you redirect, the current request vars will not be available in the redirected page. So you need to pass them on to the next.

Comment: Thanks , between  you need to put this : @$_GET['action']  , or you will keep getting an undefined error on action